# NSTextField with built in validation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, validation, nstextfield

I have in my app an NSTextField for creating a new file. I would like to have this textfield smart enough to show a small icon which show if the currently entered filename is valid (not yet exists) or not.
This icon should also change when the textfield contents change.

What is the way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is the method you are looking for:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

This is called by the textfield's delegate when the text changes. Perform your validation in the method and update your UI accordingly.